# SharePoint 2010 Newsfeed settings for privacy

Tags: 2010, newsfeed

i hope you can help me with the following question:

Who can see my Document or Workspace Activities in their newsfeed?

A: Only colleagues who have access to the document or workspace
B: All my colleagues

I would be very happy if anyone has a quick answer.

Thanks a lot.
Christian